# How do I constrain a lazy composition before I know the callable arguments?

Tags: c++, generic-programming, c++17, c++-concepts

So I'm playing around with GCC6 and its concepts implementation and I figured the Haskell Prelude would be a good source for experimenting. One of the core features of Haskell is function composition and this is something I needed to tackle straight away.

Mimicking the Haskell syntax as best that I could, I wrote this function:

```
template <typename F, typename G>
auto operator*(F f, G g)
{
  return [f, g](auto... args) {
    return f(g(args...));
  }
}
```

Which works great and allows me to do stuff like:

```
auto add([](int a, int b) { return a + b; }
auto doubled([](int a) { return a * 2; }

auto add_then_double(doubled * add);
assert(add_then_double(2, 3) == 10);
```

Happy, I decided to go back and apply some constraints to my function composition but I quickly hit a problem due to its laziness.

First I wrote this concept:

```
template <typename F, typename Ret, typename... Args>
concept bool Function()
{
  return requires(F f, Args ...args) {
    { f(args...) } -> Ret;
  }
}
```

Which I based off of the concepts found in [Andrew Sutton's origin](https://github.com/asutton/origin/blob/master/origin/core/concepts.hpp#L340) github project.

And so I tried to apply to my original function. The problem I have is that I don't know what `G` returns without knowing what arguments are passed to `G` so I can't constrain `G` and I don't know what `F` returns without knowing what parameter it is given and I don't know that because I don't know what `G` returns.

I'm pretty sure I need a new `Function` concept that doesn't care about the return type as my composition function doesn't care what `F` returns, so long as it's invokable. And I guess I could put the constraint on the inner lambda that the parameter types and correct for G and therefore for F but this means I can compose non-composable functions and won't get an error until the call site. Is this avoidable?

Maybe something like this:

```
template <typename F, typename G>
auto operator*(F f, G g)
{
  return [f, g](auto... args) 
    // is it even possible to constrain here?
    requires FunctionAnyReturn<G, decltype(args)...>
      && FunctionAnyReturn<F, decltype(G(decltype(args)...))>
  {
    return f(g(args...));
  }
}
```

Is this the best I can do (if I can even do that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, it is indeed important to put constraints at the right place. In your case it is the `operator()` of the result that must be constrained, not the composition function itself. You really can't do any better, consider for instance that many functions don't have a single return type (e.g. `std::make_tuple`). However while Concepts-Lite does touch on lambda expressions a little, it doesn’t go as far as allowing a `requires` clause on them, so your attempt will not work.

In most situations my usual advice is to write the lambda expression such that the resulting `operator()` is naturally constrained thanks to SFINAE. In your case, this means avoiding return type deduction:

```
return [f, g](auto... args) -> decltype( f(g(args...)) )
{ return f(g(args...)); }
```

If you’re using e.g. Clang, [everything is peachy](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e616bc2b2a974c93). If using GCC, you may run into a bug where [GCC performs some checking too early](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad67fe7afbeea28a).

An alternative is to go out of your way to 'unroll' the closure type of the lambda expression. By making it a user-defined type, you gain access to all the tricks and in particular you can then write the explicit constraints you want:

```
template<typename F, typename G>
struct compose_type {
    F first_composed_function;
    G second_composed_function;

    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr auto operator()(Args... args)
        // substitute in whichever concepts and traits you're actually using
        requires
            Callable<G, Args...>
            && Callable<F, result_of<G, Args...>>
    { return first_composed_function(second_composed_function(args...)); }
};

template<typename F, typename G>
constexpr compose_type<F, G> compose(F f, G g)
{ return { std::move(f), std::move(g) }; }
```

<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0833a28ffa39fc5a)</kbd>

Comment: thanks yeah this looks like the solution. it's a shame because i don't like the fact that i can compose two non-callable objects without a concept error. is there anyway i can provide a Callable variation of the callback that doesn't require the argument types upfront?

Comment: @SamKellett Not out of the box. You can choose to adhere to a protocol where function objects must make their 'signature' or something close to it available, but it's a huge undertaking for no obvious benefit.